# Is state change possible in animation triggers without any click event?

Tags: javascript, angular, animation

my animation trigger has three states:
Void, True and false.

I am using a subscription to check if there is a change in one of the variables. If there is a change, state changes to true and popup appears as per the following animation:

```
animations: [
        trigger('visibilityChanged', [
            state('void' , style({ opacity: 0})),
            state('true' , style({ opacity: 1})),
            state('false', style({ opacity: 0})),
            transition('* => *', animate('.5s'))
        ])
    ]
```

I want this popup to disappear after a short time (1s) without triggering any click event or change.

Comment: Just use a simple setTimeout and revert it back

Comment: @Milad: setTimeout approach was not working for me as after timeout, I was not able to render the HTML back. I tried the same using Renderer as well but it didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Subject for your subscription and then subscribe two times to it :

- one time for catching the change
- one time for a debounce time of 1000, for example, and then close your modal

This is an example :

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Component({
  selector: 'selfclosing-popup',
  templateUrl: 'etc.'
  animations: [
    trigger('visibilityChanged', [
        state('void' , style({ opacity: 0})),
        state('true' , style({ opacity: 1})),
        state('false', style({ opacity: 0})),
        transition('* => *', animate('.5s'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class SelfclosingPopup implements OnInit {
  changeSubject = new Subject<boolean>();
  visibilityChanged: string;    

  ngOnInit(): void {    
    this.changeSubject.subscribe((change) => this.visibilityChanged = change);
    this.changeSubject.debounceTime(1000).subscribe(() => this.visibilityChanged = false);
  }

  public notifyChange() {
    this.changeSubject.next(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Karbos, worked for me. However instead of using Subject, I subscribed to same observable twice with a debounce time of 1000ms. Thanks for the advice.